# How to upload the code in github in react?

Tags: reactjs, github

What I am trying to do is, when I try to upload my code and deploy the react app in GitHub I am getting error upon running the command `npm run deploy`.
How to fix the error, I am attaching screen shot of error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EElt.png)

any body help me out this to resolve the issue.
my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "react-hook-form-password-match-check-standard-validation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "keywords": [],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "homepage": "http://soninamrata.github.io/react-test",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-hook-form": "3.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try with homepage URL update to "https" instead of "http"? Rest things look fine.

Comment: same error i am getting i attached error  screen shot above

Comment: can you help me out this

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EElt.png this error i am getting

Comment: There seems to be some issue with your build script. Do "npm run build" and try to fix that. Then run the deploy script

Comment: Also update the name in package.json to "react-test" (same as in homepage URL) and try again?

Comment: https://ibb.co/KmDQNPv when i run npm run build this error show

Comment: after when i run react-scripts build then also getting error

Comment: any idea how to fix

Comment: Could you update the name to "react-test" instead the one you have and try again? (Making it same as present in the homepage URL)

Comment: Ok but where can i update the name "react-test"????

Comment: If you notice, you have set "name": "react-hook-form-password-match-check-standard-validation"
Change this to "name": "react-test" (1st line after "{")

Comment: ok will try and i will let u know

Comment: i changed the name but same error i am getting

Comment: can you help me out this error image https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EElt.png